# SVN status filter by * (newer version exists)

Tags: svn

I'm on a linux system and I want to show out-of-date files with who committed them.

I can see committer name when using --verbose, but I only want to see out-of-date files.

So when I do an `svn status -u -v` I get a huge list of files - I just want to see the * files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
svn status -u -v | grep "........\*"
```